# Could not load file or assembly 'Spire.License, Version=1.3.2.40, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b1144360237c8b3f' or one of its dependencies

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, spire, spire.doc

I am using Spire.Xls in my web project to create an excel sheet on the fly.In local every thing is working fine but once i deployed it on the Server , it is throwing exception as

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Spire.License, Version=1.3.2.40, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b1144360237c8b3f' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
>   File name: 'Spire.License, Version=1.3.2.40, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b1144360237c8b3f'

Please find below the detailed error log :-

> === Pre-bind state information ===
>   LOG: User = IIS APPPOOL\ASP.NET v4.0
>   LOG: DisplayName = Spire.License, Version=1.3.2.40, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b1144360237c8b3f
>    (Fully-specified)
>   LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/ePareeksha/ePareeksha/
>   LOG: Initial PrivatePath = C:\ePareeksha\ePareeksha\bin
>
> ## Calling assembly : Spire.XLS, Version=7.1.0.7040, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=663f351905198cb3.

LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\ePareeksha\ePareeksha\web.config
LOG: Using host configuration file: c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet.config
LOG: Using machine configuration file from c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Post-policy reference: Spire.License, Version=1.3.2.40, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b1144360237c8b3f
LOG: The same bind was seen before, and was failed with hr = 0x80070002.

Please guide me that how i will fix this .

Comment: You could contact with specialized support service of Spire.XLS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try to copy the Spire.License.dll to the path where you place the Spire.Xls.dll (which is referenced at runtime) and make sure they are placed  in same folder.

Answer (score 0):

Is the `Spirel.License.dll` present on the server in the working directory? Or is it registered in the GAC? Ie have you done

```
c:\gacutil /i path\to\dllname.dll
```

The exception states that the system cannot find the referenced dll.

Another thing you could try is to set "Copy Local" to `true` in the properties for the reference.

Comment: Copy Local in the properties of reference is true only.In My local machine also i checked at C:\windows\assembly , Spire.xls.dll is not there but here it is working fine. Tried to register this dll on production server using regsvr32 -i "location" but getting error.

Comment: regsvr is not for .NET dlls.. Use gacutil.